# Clean a URL so "/../" are removed

Tags: php, directory, backtracking

Is there a PHP way of processing a user entered **URL** so instead of:

http://example.com/directory/../index.php

it becomes

http://example.com/index.php

while preserving everything else such as query parameters intact?

Preferrably without regular expressions or string replacing. Something more universal and not OS dependant if possible, please.

*EDIT: To add some context, my script is dynamically building the above URL, which leads to a specific script on my website and I am passing the resulting URL to a Google+ Login API as a callback/redirect URL, but Google doesn't accept such "non-standard" characters in the callback URL.*

Comment: Those two URLs aren't necessarily equivalent. A web server is free to interpret ".." any way it wishes, it doesn't have to mean "parent directory".

Comment: @user1986811 not an option since I am passing the URL to a third party service, not redirecting to it. The third party service doesn't accept such "non-standard" URLs that contain "/../". See edited question for clarification.

Comment: @deceze correct, but the third party service I am passing the URL to doesn't accept such directory backtracking. It needs a clean URL. See the edited question for context.

Comment: _my script is dynamically building the above URL_ This rather tells that your script works wrong. It should generate valid URLs.

Comment: By "script" I meant "framework" (Yii). Unfortunately, I can't modify the framework just to fit this specific purpose, but rather I need to post-process the resulting generated URL.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet could do the trick in a PHP way, with no regular expressions:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/data/data2/data3/../../page.html";
$parts = explode("/",$url);
while ($index = array_search('..', $parts)) {
    unset($parts[$index]);
    unset($parts[$index-1]);
    $parts = array_values($parts);
}
```

The call to array_values is required to reindex the $parts array, to handle the case where ".." appears more than once, as shown in the example.

Just to take into account the case when the query string includes the substring "/../", the snippet can be improved as:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/data/data2/data3/../../page.html?url=/../b";
$pieces = explode("?",$url);
$parts = explode("/",$pieces[0]);
while ($index = array_search('..', $parts)) {
    unset($parts[$index]);
    unset($parts[$index-1]);
    $parts = array_values($parts);
}
if (count($pieces)>1) {
    echo join("?",array(join("/",$parts),$pieces[1])) . "\n";
} else {
    echo join("/",$parts) . "\n";
}
```